# msi table information

Tags: windows-installer, orca

At http://support.microsoft.com/kb/255905 usoft says there is a file msi.chm distributed as part of the sdk.  I have sdk v7 and can't find hide nor hair of this file.  What I'm really after are the table names and row names for all the item that can appear under Support Information in the Add/Remove Programs under the control panel.  Things like Publisher, Version, Contact, Support Info, Support Telephone, Readme, Product Updates.  It appears Publisher comes from the Manufacturer row in the Property table and Version comes from the Version row under the Property table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Readme is specified in a property ARPREADME (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa367746(VS.85).aspx). I've seen other ARPsomething properties (ARP stands for Add/Remove Programs), so some of the things you're looking for are not in the schema definition.

Things like publisher and version are probably taken from summary information stream, but I'm guessing here.

Comment: Thanks, the 'Property Reference' tells a lot about these. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370905(VS.85).aspx
Rows I might be interested in include...
Manufacturer, ProductVersion, ARPCONTACT, ARPHELPLINK, ARPHELPTELEPHONE, ARPREADME,ARPURLUPDATEINFO, ARPCONTACTS, ARPURLINFOABOUT